# How to automatically find the threshold and sigma values for Canny Edge Detection?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection, canny-operator, image-thresholding

I want to find the range of threshold values used and sigma values used for specific images. For example, If there is a set of images of different types such as too bright and high contrast, too bright and low contrast, not bright and high contrast, How can I know what range of threshold values and sigma values I should use? How does the object in the image for example a transparent bottle picture vs flower picture affects these values.

Comment: Are you specially worried about this? Have you tried just using whatever is default? Ultimately the values that canny edge will output are only relevant relatively to the ones in the same image. The output is "edge", as "25 edge" means nothing by itself, only relatively to a smaller valued "3 edge".  You dont care if these values are 25-3 or 2.5-0.3. Surely the parameters you describe are a bit more complex than what I say, but [you know how it is with these tasks](https://xkcd.com/1425/), unless you have an specific problem, you may as well just not worry.

Comment: Maybe this [paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5476095/)  helps you

Comment: This is purely subjective, and depends entirely on image contents, and what you deem to be strong edges versus not-so-useful edges. The MATLAB `edge` function does a best guess estimate of the thresholds (if you don't provide them as inputs) using the sub-function: `selectThresholds` in the file `edge.m`. It may so happen that this works well for your set of images. If not, you'd have to come up with something similar, based on your subjective assessment of what good edges are. The default for sigma in the MATLAB implementation seems to be sqrt(2).

Comment: Thank you much. I was just thinking to find a guideline so that by looking at a picture, the threshold and sigma can be guessed within a range depending on how bright and light they are. Thanks for your time.